# How to set multiple data sources in Spring Data R2DBC

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc

I am using spring data r2dbc in my new project and need to connect multiple data sources like A data source and B data source.
Is there a way to connect multiple data sources using r2dbc?
Could I get an example or a document if there is a way?

My stacks are below:

- Spring Boot 2.3.0.M4
- Spring WebFlux
- Spring Data R2DBC

Answer (score 6):

If you want to use multiple datasources in a single application, check my [multi r2dbc connection factories example](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-puzzles/tree/master/multi-r2dbc-connectionfactories).

If you need a multi-tenant like feature check [this multi-tenancy-r2dbc example](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-puzzles/tree/master/multi-tenancy-r2dbc).

Comment: Thanks for your answering 

They will be helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue using `AbstractRoutingConnectionFactory` you can check  [Add support for AbstractRoutingConnectionFactory](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-r2dbc/commit/e3aae619f416645314c9f9bd0ce5ddfa874a30b9?fbclid=IwAR1eP9NLLVOHarFX5FF_faxG2Q2Ceh-WmsaS1SubcZAN0FlLMjfZTDwIfm4)

Comment: Any more details on this solution? Can you point specific repos or entities different database connections?

Comment: @Eric check my complete multi-tenancy-r2dbc example in my answer.